# How to bypass this specific type error in python? Trying to set a function == True

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to create a simulation where one class (Gargoyles) follows another class (Kids). What I want to happen is that when the two classes meet on the same space, the gargoyle kills a kid. What I've tried so far hasn't worked and my current method is trying to call a function that sets the specific kids 'self.petrified' to equal true. Currently however it isn't working and I keep getting a type error that tells me 'list indicies must be intergers or slices, not kid'. Is there anyway to bypass this?

Code for gargoyle movement/killing

````m
                n = gargoyleList[e].getCol()

                dist = []
                for d in kidList:
                    dist.append(math.sqrt(((kidList[d].getRow() - m)**2)+((kidList[d].getCol()-n)**2)))
                    target = len(min(dist))


                o = target.getRow
                p = target.getCol

                if m > o:
                    x = 2
                    gargoyleList[e].setminusRow(x)
                else:
                    x = 2
                    gargoyleList[e].setplusRow(x)
                if n > p:
                    x = 2
                    gargoyleList[e].setminusCol(x)
                else:
                    x = 2
                    gargoyleList[e].setplusCol(x)
                if m == o and n == p:
                    kidList[e].life()```

###Code for when a kid gets killed:
```def life(self):
        self.petrified == True```
````

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. We can't run it to reproduce your problem. Show us (1) the definition of class `kid` and (2) the complete traceback, not a retyped version of the error message. Please [edit] your question to provide this. Otherwise your question is likely to get closed for insufficient detail.

Comment: you have `target.getCol` while also having `gargoyleList[e].getCol()`, don't you mean `target.getCol()`?  Also your question as it is makes it impossible for anyone else but you to answer as the problem(s) you mentioned are incomplete, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or edit as suggested.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.